# Open explorer with file selected, if not open already

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, batch-file, cmd.exe

Using `cmd`, I am able to open Explorer to a specific path with a specific file highlighted:

`explorer /select, c:\test\file.txt`

However, this opens a new instance of Explorer each time, even if this location is open already.

I would like Explorer to open and highlight the file if it's not open already. But if it *is* open to that path, to give that Explorer window focus and highlight the specified file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

With autohotkey it will be simple script (not tried, you need to fix syntax probably)

```
   run explorer.exe,  "folder"
sleep 500 
send, "filename.txt"
```

Update: You can compile autohotkey script into exe and run from cmd if needed.

Comment: Thanks Eduard. I specifically need this to be a `cmd` command though.

Comment: You can compile autohotkey into exe and run from cmd

Answer (score 0):

Use the `start` command instead of `explorer`.  If an existing Explorer window is open at that path, it gives it focus.  Otherwise, it creates a new Explorer window.

Example: `start C:`

Comment: `/select` doesn't seem to be a valid switch for `start`. Is there a way to have it start with a file highlighted, like `/select` does?

Comment: This solution seems to only work for folders.  I think specifically calling `explorer` always creates a new instance.

Comment: Yeah looks like it. Highlighting the file is what I need to accomplish. Thanks for the attempt though!